# Get only files but not directories in QT?

Tags: file, qt, directory

When I do this:

```
QDir myDir("/home/some/location");
QStringList filesList = myDir.entryList("*");
```

it is returning both the files and the directories inside that location. But I want only files. And the files can have arbitrary extensions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use  [QDir::entryInfoList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdir.html#entryInfoList)  to return a list of QFileInfo objectsd and then check the state of each of them, you can also use filters to only return a list of files /and/or dirs

Answer (score 10):

Use this

```
QDir recoredDir("YOUR DIRECTORY");
    QStringList allFiles = recoredDir.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::System | QDir::Hidden  | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files, QDir::DirsFirst);//(QDir::Filter::Files,QDir::SortFlag::NoSort)
```

;

Comment: This gets directories too (on my Windows machine)

Comment: In blackberry 10 devices it will return only files.