# How to display the names of all files in a folder in a window? Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

In the software I'm creating, I have a window where I want to list all the files below each other.
I tried a solution but the list is too small compared to the size of the window ....I would like the list to take up all the space of my window.

Here is my code :

```
viewList::viewList(){

QString path="/home/myFolder";
QListWidget *listwidget=new QListWidget;
QVBoxLayout *vbox=new QVBoxLayout;

foreach(QString file, files){

    listwidget->addItem(file);
    vbox->addWidget(listwidget);
}
  this->setLayout(vbox);
}
```

et dans le .h :

```
class viewList : public QWidget{
 ///
}
```

Has anyone ever had this problem to solve?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only files but not directories in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709070/get-only-files-but-not-directories-in-qt)

Comment: `vbox->addWidget(listwidget);` in your loop, is bad to add the same widget in the same layout for each file

Comment: No, my question is not exactly the same. Because I can recover the files. But when I post them they do not take up all the space of my window .....

Comment: @Thibaut B. ok thank you. I understood my error. I placed vbox->addwidget outside the loop...

Comment: You don't need to create a list widget for each file you have. Instead you have to create a single list widget and add list **items** to it using, for example, `QListWidget::addItem()` function.

Comment: @Thomas1314, this fix give you a better result ?

Comment: @Thibaut B. Yes now my list takes the whole place of the window.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm sorry I will do what you told me in my next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put this line `vbox->addWidget(listwidget);` outside the loop because it's create a layout emplacement for the same widget for each file.
By doing this, the listWidget can't take all the place of your parent widget.

**Correct solution:**

```
foreach(QString file, files){    
    listwidget->addItem(file);
}
vbox->addWidget(listwidget);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I have a new problem then...beacause I want to add in a item A file, the date and a QLabel for each iteration but I can not do listwidget->addItem(nameLabel). ....

Comment: @Tom13000, you can concatenate the file string with other string when you add the item. If concatenate isn't sufficient, maybe implement your own model. For file info, look [*QFileInfo*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html)

Comment: ok thanks but Knowing that for each item I need the date (QString), the file (QString) and a QLabel. Would the simplest solution be to go through QListWidget and QListWidgetItem? I do not see how to concatenate two QString ...

Comment: My problem is that I want to add for each file its date (QString), a Qlabel and the file name (QString).

Comment: @Tom13000, a QLabel is to display text, you don't need it if you concatenate string when you add your item.

Comment: Thank you @Thibaut B. it works